# DatagridView only shows rows if I click on the row

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, windows

I'm working on a windows app. When I click on the linkLabel to load data from sql into my DatagridView, the grid shows blank rows and reveals the data only if I click on the rows. Here are some pics:
This is the print when I load the data into the Grid from a buttonClick
[image]

This is the print when I click on the arrow to select the hole row
[image]

I want to see all the data from the first click. Here is the code for the buttonClick:

```
    private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        comando.CommandText = "Select * from compras order by importância";

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView11.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `dataGridView11.Refresh()`

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: You aren't getting to the posted code until you click the row.  Put a break point (F9) on the Open() method in your code and test when it actually gets to the break point.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of custom painting on this DGV?

Comment: @Equalsk no, the weird thing is that i have other 10 datagridviews doing basically the same job and all of them work, this is the only one with an error and i am using the same logic in all of them

Comment: If you deselect the row, does the data "disappear" again? Has the row's, cell's, or grid's `ForeColor` been changed to white?

Comment: @OhBeWise I haven't tried that yet, I'll check and tell you later, but the thing is that when I click on the label, the first cell is already selected, so I don't know if I'll be able to deselect the row. I'm almost sure any of them are white, but who knows right? I'll check on that too.

Comment: Have you made any progress?  To deselect the row, I just meant selecting a different cell.  If they do indeed have white text, then only the selected cell(s) would have visible text on the blue backgrounds.

Comment: @OhBeWise Not yet. I'm almost sure that the text is white. But i don't see any option that can change the color on the dgv

Comment: @OhBeWise Problem solved! The issue was indeed the white text! I just could not find where to change it

Comment: I thought so.  If you were able to correct it, don't forget to post an answer and after the wait period - accept it so this post can be marked as resolved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was on the DGV **settings**. The font color was wrongly set as white. 
The only weird thing was that the others DGV that i used in my app were normal